# Yii Simple RBAC Error

Tags: php, yii

I just a newbie in Yii. I have read http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/ and followed all instructions there, but I had error User.roles is not defined when I tried to login. Here is my UserIdentity.php

```
<?php
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
private $_id;

public function authenticate()
{
    $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array
            ('username'=>$this->username));

    if($user===null){
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    }
    else{
        if($user->password!==$user->encrypt($this->password)){
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        }
        else{
            $this->_id = $user->username;
            $this->setState('roles', $user->roles);
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}

public function getId(){
    return $this->_id;
}
}
```

And then EWebUser.php

```
<?php 
class EWebUser extends CWebUser
{
    public function checkAccess($operation, $params=array())
    {
        if (empty($this->id)) {
            // Not identified => no rights
            return false;
        }
        $role = $this->getState("roles");
        if ($role === 'admin') {
            return true; // admin role has access to everything
        }
        // allow access if the operation request is the current user's role
        return ($operation === $role);
    }
}
```

At last accessRules method in UserController.php

```
public function accessRules()
{
      .....
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            //'users'=>array('admin'),
            'roles'=>array('admin'),
    .....
    );
}
```

I hope anyone can help me solve this problwm, thank you very much

Comment: do you using user and rights extension?

Comment: no, I didn't use it. I just follow instructions in that article

Comment: [SOLVED] solved by myself, I forgot to change "role" to "roles" in my table in database, simple looks like complex, happy coding